# Determining the dimension of the kernel and the dimension of the image of the linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine the dimension of the kernel and the dimension of the image of the linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ given by:
>   $$T(x,y,z)^T=(x-y+z,x+2y-z,2x+y,3y-2z)^T$$

**My try:**
$$x\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}\\\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$$ I don't know how to proceed further. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Do you know how to reduce the matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember what you're trying to solve here. The expression

$$x\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$$

is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$. You have to ask yourself, what does it have to do with the question? What are you trying to find out here? What does the kernel even mean?

The kernel is the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that map to the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ under $T$. Our map $T$ does the following:

$$T\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x−y+z \\x+2y−z \\2x+y \\3y−2z\end{bmatrix} = x\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$$

When does it send the vector to $0$? When $x, y, z$ satisfy

$$\begin{bmatrix}x−y+z \\x+2y−z \\2x+y \\3y−2z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Equating entries yields the system of equations,

\begin{align*}
x - y + z &= 0 \\ x + 2y - z &= 0 \\ 2x + y &= 0 \\ 3y - 2z &= 0.
\end{align*}

Now it's a matter of solving this system, which we can do with an augmented matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Or, if you're comfortable, you can omit the $0$ column. If you're comfortable, you can skip some of these steps and go straight to the matrix.

But, as is my point, only if you're comfortable! If you don't know/understand this stuff, then you can get lost along the shortcuts!

From here, Gauss-Jordan elimination gives:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -\frac{2}{3} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$

which translates to

\begin{align*}
x + \frac{z}{3} &= 0 \\
y - \frac{2z}{3} &= 0.
\end{align*}

If we let $z = 3t$, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x = -t$ and $y = 2t$. This gives us a solution of

$$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -t \\ 2t \\ 3t \end{bmatrix} = t\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

as $t$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}$. This means our kernel is

$$\operatorname{Ker}(T) = \operatorname{span} \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

It is the span of a single non-zero (hence, linearly independent) vector, hence the kernel is of dimension $1$ (i.e. $\operatorname{null} T = 1$). Using the rank-nullity theorem,
$$3 = \operatorname{dim} \mathbb{R}^3 = \operatorname{rank} T + \operatorname{null} T = \operatorname{rank} T + 1$$
which implies $\operatorname{rank} T = 2$, which is the dimension of the image.